# What is the proper name for a backward forecast?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

Suppose in time series you have the data in a recent period and you would like to use that data to extrapolate backward to get estimates of the time series back in time. What do you call that? ? Extrapolating forward is forecast, so hindcast?

Comment: As Rob Hyndman suggests (and really, he's the expert), backcast is the most common term.

Comment: I've only encountered hindcast, so it may differ by field

Answer (score 6):

Backcast, although I have seen hindcast as well.

Comment: I used hindcast and senior management was asking whether this is the correct term.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just learning Timeseries now but found this wonderful paper: Caporin and Sartore use the term back-calculation. They acknowledge it's not a common term, noting other used terms: retropolation, reconstruction, and back-casting (ARIMA).

see end of section 2:
Caporin, M., & Sartore, D. (2006). Methodological aspects of time series back-calculation.